# c++ command line arguments in ubuntu terminal

Tags: c++, command-line

This is a really basic question but I am just beginning to use command line arguments in my programs. Normally I would compile the program in terminal with `g++ example.cpp`
Then I would type `./a.out` and would do the `cout`/`cin` back and forth.

My question is, after I have compiled the program, what do I type in the terminal to let it know I am about to input the arguments?

Comment: `./a.out arg1 arg2 arg3`, for example.

Comment: cin and cout are how c++ can communicate via stdin and stdout. The arguments are a different thing, not stdin or stdout.

Answer (score 3):

Create an output file of the same program. Do it by entering this in the terminal:

```
g++ example.cpp -o example
```

When compiled, run the program as:

```
./example arg1 arg2
```

Even the above method by @Petr Budnik works.

Answer (score 0):

You define command line arguments when you first invoke the program.  For example, the command `cp ~/file.txt ~/folder/` takes the command line arguments "cp", "~/file.txt", and "~/folder/".  Do note that the first argument in an array of command line arguments is the name of the program itself.